# how to store a variable and its value in data-structure?

Tags: javascript, data-structures

```js
let v = {a:1}
let s = new Set();
s.add(v);
v = null;
```

at this time , s still has one element : `{a:1}` 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIsMv.png)

I guess `v` and `{a:1}`  are stored in different places, but I need an authoritative theory to explain this .
it seems about heap and stack?

Comment: cause `s.add(v)` just copy the value of v, and add to set `s`

Answer (score 0):

```
let v = {a:1}
let s = new Set();
s.add(v);
v.b = 2;
```

at this time , `s`  has one element : `{a:1,b:2}`.

However, I've learned ，`v` and `{a:1}` are two
different things.

if set `b = null`,just change the pointer that  `b` point to .